# How to use another Git-Project within mine but revision the used remote version

Tags: git, github

What I have:

- A team of programmers =)
- My **main** git repo
- **Another** git repo (contains e.g. a library or bundle I want to use)

What I want:

- Check out the **other project** into a subfolder of my **main project**
- Each teammate should **automatically get the new subfolder** and the related files of **the version I checked out** when they pull
- When someone **pulls explicitly the subfolder** he will update his files to the latest remote version. If he commits that afterwards, all teammates should **get the new files automatically when pulling next time the main repo**.

What would be nice:

- When I **edit** / **commit** / **push** /... **the subfolder** (and I have access rights to the other project), it should be **treated like i directly edited the other project**. Again **all teammates should get the version I checked in next time they pull** the main repo.

I tried with `submodules`, but it does not meet my requirements. Also I found a lot of posts to `subtrees` etc. but still no clear answer.

So, if someone knows a >=90% solution, he can make my day.
Thanks!